# How to use a variable in bash between ' '

Tags: linux, bash

I want to print the last line of a text file in shell the number of lines in my text are stored in a variable named n when I try to use sed command like this sed -n '$np' I get an error.How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You would use double quotes: `sed -n "${n}p" your_file.txt`, but you don't need `sed` for this. Just use `tail`:

```
tail -n 1 your_file.txt
```